# Close MS Project using VSTO

Tags: vb.net, vsto, ms-project

I have a VSTO on MS Project. I use VB.NET. What I need is when I press the button I created on the ribbon, it will perform some codes which will update the info of some task, however, I would need to close the MS Project automatically. I tried application.FileCloseEx(), but it only closes the file, the MS Project is still loaded. I need similar to clicking the x button of the window.

Thanks,
Gilbert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your MS Project application object is represented by "appMSProject" then it's as simple as:

```
appMSProject.Quit
```

OR say in a macro running under Project:

```
Application.Quit
```

Here's how I do it in VBA from Excel or Access. As far as I can tell the objects & methods are the same in VB.NET. Bottom line is that I create an instance of the MS Project object which starts the app & opens a file, execute some work, close the file, then destroy the MS Project object by setting it to Nothing. That has the effect of closing the app. You can also use "appMSProject.Quit" followed by setting it to Nothing. Frankly the 2nd option looks more orderly & easier to understand in code. Anyway, here's a sample of the way I do it:

```
Dim appMSProject As MSProject.Application
Dim prjPrj As MSProject.Project
Dim strPrjFile As String

strPrjFile = "C:\where_is_my_file\file_name.mpp"

Set appMSProject = New MSProject.Application
appMSProject.FileOpenEx Name:=strPrjFile
Set prjPrj = appMSProject.ActiveProject

'''Do something in here with the prjPrj

'Close the file, in my case w/o saving
appMSProject.FileCloseEx pjDoNotSave


'Destroy the objects
Set prjPrj = Nothing
Set appMSProject = Nothing
```

FYI - In this example I'm doing background work so I don't show the app. I also use "early binding".

Here's an MSDN example that does show the app with more info on early -vs- late binding - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865152.aspx

Comment: Hi,I was able to do that after I sent the question. However, can I have a new question for you? how will i get the complete path of the opened MS Project.

Comment: Hi Jack, I found the answer, ActiveProject.Fullname

Comment: Gilbert, cool! The other thing I do all the time, in case you don't know how to do this, is to start the macro recorder, do what I want to automate by clicking & keyboarding, stop the recorder, then edit the freshly recorded macro in the VBA editor. It's never really very reusable code, but it almost always exposes objects & parameters. Great time saver as you may already know. Best!